# How to open Google Plus link external from app?

Tags: android

How do you open a Google Plus link external from your own app? ie. Chrome, G+ app.
I tried using something like this:

```
    String url = "https://plus.google.com/+google";
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
```

At first it looks like it launched the G+ app but if you press the task switcher you'll see the link actually loads within your own app.

Comment: i tried it on my emulator without G+ app it works as expected. whats your use case?

Comment: You're right, I disabled G+ and it worked as expected. I just have a client who wants to keep their social media separated from the app. It's just weird everything else works by going out of the app except for G+.